# Chroot, pivot_root with fallback

Tags: linux, chroot

Consider a small Linux system with network capabilities but with limited storage.

So, it can mount a nice fully-customized rootfs via nfs, and it can chroot (or pivot_root) into it.

Everything is fine until this point.

Now consider a network failure between the nfs server and the client.
Of course the system will hang.

**Is there a safe way to run an application which periodically checks weather the nfs is healthy and when it goes down it chroots (pivot_roots) back into the original, small rootfs?** (which then will keep retrying to restore the nfs)

Or is this needed at all? Or NFS will take care of this unattended?

My fear is that in case of network outage if a running program needs something from the storage it will crash. So even if NFS restores itself the program won't be restarted, and I think not all Linux programs are coded that error-prone way.

So the best way would be to safely chroot back to the original small rootfs (which is a nice and safe readonly one), which then can reinit everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do anything clever, it is not needed, and it will break.

Configure nfs mount to never timeout, and never report timeout errors. That way as long as the app has no timeouts (not very badly written). It will be fine.

I worked on a system with several thin client (no disk) everything mounted via NFS (including swap). We could reboot the NFS server or disconnect cables, the clients would freeze, then carry-on when the server came back. This is expected behaviour.

However you need to ensure that the mounts don't use the optional timeout option.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working as I'd expect. The network access is provided via wlan0 if. However now I just have seen that it lost it's IP association. Small tech question (as I don't have a chance to test now): udhcpd is running on the local rootfs. After doing the pivot_root, will it remain in running state (and receive the network disassocation event)?

Comment: As the network fails something has to take care of 'reiniting' things: wlan0 connection and getting a new dhcp address. (or perhaps completely rebooting).
Can I run a watchdog on the small local rootfs which will keep running even after pivot_root?

Comment: I have created a new question which relates to this one: https://superuser.com/questions/1498171/nfs-rootfs-over-wifi-with-fallback